# Firefox: disable "search" in autocomplete url/location bar

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, omnibox

How to disable the "search" suggestions in autocomplete url/location bar?

For example, in this screenshot

[image: pic]

I would like to **remove** the lower part:

[image: pic]

Comment: please always upload images to the built-in stack.imgur which will never expire, otherwise external links may rot, rendering the question invalid like this

Answer (score 2):

- Enter `about:config` in the URL bar
- find the entry `browser.urlbar.oneOffSearches`
- set the value of this entry to `false`

That's it, firefox should autocomplete your pages without any "search" stuff now.

Answer (score 0):

To disable searches from search providers such as DuckDuckGo in the URL bar:

1. Go to `about:config` in your URL bar
2. Search for `keyword.enabled` and set it to false